# C: searching strings in a dictionary

Tags: c, search, optimization

I have an algorithm where I have created a huge set(dictionary) of strings. Now I have another huge stream of strings arriving serially and need to be looked up whether present in dictionary or not. I am able to implement this scenario till now. Now I want that if any string arrives twice or multiple times , I need to mark it as 'existing' without searching again. How can we achieve this ? I can't think of any way without storing already parsed strings in some way. If we store already parsed strings and then check every string whether it came earlier or not, that would be an overhead which kills the intention of optimization. Any ideas?

Comment: 0) simplest: construct a hash table from the dictonary strings 2) harder: construct a DFA from the dictionary strings. 3) construct a suffix tree / patricia tree / trie from the strings in the dictionary.

Comment: I actually have dictionary in form of trie itself

Comment: If your only goal is to detect (or count) duplicates, you could add one bit (or count field) to every terminal node. (the same technique would work for a hashtable, and even for a DFA)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check every string in order to tell whether you've seen one before. This kind of problem is usually solved with a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which will let you know whether an element is in table or not in constant time (well, it could, but it depends on implementation).

Or you can use [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which will be able to quickly tell you whether an item has not been seen yet, though it has a downside of having false positives. I.e. it reliably tells you if something is not in the set, but tells you "maybe" otherwise and you have to perform further checks.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of a hashtable is the best solution here. It has optimized functions in order to process this work quickly. Simple adding each string to the hhashtable will give You the check implicitely.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you strings array sorted. Searching will be O(log N) instead of O(N) that gives a huge performance boost.

Comment: Why are you assuming he's using arrays?